# Power Automate Flow that gets user information from SharePoint and updates excel spreadsheet

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I am trying to create a simple flow, that will collect information when a user clicks on a button in a SharePoint site. Essentially all I need is the user who clicked the button email and date and time of the button click.

I would then like to update a excel spreadsheet with this information.

It seems like quite a simple flow, but I haven't been able to work it out, all help is greatly appreciated!

I have tried several different options, including searching far and wide for an answer but no solution.

Comment: What does the button do?

Comment: We have a spreadsheet full of tasks that users will complete throughout the day. Currently, they will go to their SharePoint site and click a button when they are ready to complete the task, and then fill out a form which collects their email and the time of beginning the task, which will then assign them to the next available task in the spreadsheet.

Instead of using clicking through the form to begin their tasks, I was hoping to be able to collect those details (email, time, date) from the click of a button.

Comment: So the button sends them off to a Microsoft Form or some other kind of form?  Is there any chance of showing screenshots of the basic process in SharePoint and the surrounding applications itself?

Comment: Currently it sends them to a microsoft form which collects their email and time of form completion, which then updates a row in excel with which user has started this task. (The excel also has other practical uses). I am trying to bypass the form by just collecting the user (who will be logged in their account) and time when they click the button and then using this information to update the row in excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON column formatting to show a button in the SharePoint list view and then configure the JSON to run a specific workflow.

The specifics are too much for an answer here. The crucial bit in the JSON code is this command, which has the workflow GUID as a parameter.

```
"customRowAction": {
    "action": "executeFlow",
    "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"edfddddd-6bbd-483f-87a1-26fdc3264a34\"}"
},
```

You can find samples online, for instance in this article:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/use-json-formatting-to-create-button-and-trigger-power-automate-flow/

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.